# Can't get php code to work. Echo displays the word "echo"

Tags: php, html, web, echo

Taking an internet programming class and our first assignment was to grab input from an html form and echo it out in a php page. After many frustrating attempts to get this to work, I just tried to make a php page that echoes out "hello world" but not even that worked. It echoed out "echo 'hello world';"

When I try to view my php files in chrome, I just get the source code to display but I want to be able to view it as if it were a webpage.

I don't know how to show my code properly on here. Anytime I try to combine < with ?, it just shows up as

Ok. I've got the hello world one working, but now I have an issue where I can't echo out variables.

Got it working! My local server wasn't on, and then for the actual assignment the syntax was wrong. Thanks for all your help and patience!

Comment: Hi, please show us all the code of your `Hello World` script. And the other one if you like. As with most questions on SO you will always get a better response if you include some code we can see

Comment: Most obvious other possible issue! Did you install a web server with PHP configured within it?

Comment: Show your code please i can 100% be sure its an out of place symbol/apostrophe or something like that

Comment: To the Chrome browser, a .php file is just a text file. You need to have the file on a PHP server, such as Apache, for it to do anything - the server will take the php commands and turn them (eventually) into HTML that the browser can understand. OK, that's oversimplifying things, but hopefully you get the idea!

Comment: Is there a tutorial video or something similar you could link me to? I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing. This is the first time I've studied web development in about four years and back then I only barely had a grasp on html and css; we didn't even get into php.

Comment: does the url in the browser address bar start with `file:////` or `http://`

Comment: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/hello_world.php is what I type in

Comment: Then you did not install a web server or you are not using it if you did. You can run HTML and Javascript raw in a browser, but you need a web server configured with PHP to run PHP code. Take a look at WAMPServer or XAMPP

Comment: I have XAMPP installed

Comment: Re edit: If you have a new question, then [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Make sure you include a [mcve]. If you are still having trouble formatting code in your question, look more closely at the formatting buttons along the top of the editor box.

Answer (score 0):

Ensuring that your file is saved with the extension .php:

```
<?php

echo 'Hello World';

?>
```

Comment: That's letter for letter what my code is but when I open the file in chrome, it displays the source code and not the message.

Comment: are you sure your server has PHP installed and is correctly configured to parse .php files with it?

Comment: I don't recall installing anything.

Answer (score 0):

1.- `"echo 'hello world';"` is wrong, should be

`<html>
    <?php echo "Hello World!"; ?>
</html>`

2.- You need a server, you can't only open file with the explorer, check apache or nginx.

Answer (score 0):

You should not load php files directly. Instead, make sure your XAMPP servers are running [help on that here](https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_windows.html), and navigate your browser to http://localhost/hello_world.php